# Could not find mime-types-1.23 in any of the sources

Tags: rubygems, rake

When I run the command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, I get the error:

```
Could not find mime-types-1.23 in any of the sources
```

Then I run: `gem list`

among the output there is:

```
mail (2.5.4)
**mime-types (1.23)**
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.7)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
```

What can be done?

Comment: What is the output of `bundle list`?

Comment: /usr/share/redmine$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
Could not find mime-types-1.23 in any of the sources

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes the output: Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /home/kobi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247

Comment: Now try running `bundle list` again. If you see `mime-types`, then try your original command: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. If not, please update your question with the output of `bundle list`.

Comment: bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
Could not find mime-types-1.23 in any of the sources

Comment: I change the Gemfile and commented out the 'gem mime-types' and now the output is: Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.3.5)

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the contents of your Gemfile, as well as the outputs of `bundle -v`, `gem -v`, and `ruby -v`.